# Which RadioButton will be added first on JavaFX ToggleGroup

Tags: javafx, radio-button

> Description

I have two `RadioButtons` and they both are on the `ToggleGroup` named `fileSearchGroup` , i make them using `SceneBuilder 8` , below is an image :

[image]

> Question

So the two `RadioButtons` are added as shown above. If i change them so the one named `File Absolute Path...` goes down and the other named `File Name...` comes up , **which one will be the first and which will be the second on the `ToggleGroup` named `fileSearchGroup`**?

Why i want to know that ?

Because inside the application i have this code (below is some pseudocode):

```
//Get the index of the selected toggle
if(group.getSelectedToggleIndex() == 0)
   //Search using absolute path
else 
   //Search using file name
```

> Finally

Is there a solution for the above or do i have to add `ID` to the `RadioButtons` which i don't want to do , cause of code complexity it adds when i save database settings.

- Why i don't want to use `ID`

I am saving settings using `KeyValue` database , so the `Key` is for example `SearchFilesUsing` and the value is a number like `0` or `1` based on the selected `RadioButton` index inside `ToggleGroup` , if i add `ID` then it makes the work hard and if i want to change the `ID` on future i will have to change again code here and there.

Comment: Why don't you just inject the radio buttons into your controller (e.g. `fx:id="absolutePathRadioButton"`) and do `if (group.getSelectedToggle() == absolutePathRadioButton)` ???

Comment: @James_D Hello James :) . I have added a `Finally` section on the question of why i don't use ID's for the `RadioButtons` , i have a `Key-Value` database and if i change any ID in future application releases it will brake the database . I have build it such that if i change it now it will brake it for the users that are using it . Maybe a bad  decision . I will rethink on how to make it like you say though.

Comment: I'm not suggesting mapping an id. I'm suggesting just using the reference to the object itself.

Comment: @James_D OK , so the key is `Search_Files_Using` , what should i use for `value` so when i get the value from the `key-value` database to get the exact `RadioButton` the user has selected before closing the application ? By the way i am saving it to a Property File using [Java Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) , the most simple way .

Comment: Use some string constants and set them as user data in the controls if needed. The bottom line is you have to have some arbitrary mapping between what's in the file and what's selected. There's no reason to trust an int more than anything else. Relying on the implementation details of the toggle group is way less robust than explicitly coding something yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have some mapping between what's in your file (essentially a string, or a string representation of some other data type) and the radio buttons. There's no real reason to trust an `int` more than anything else.

You could just use some string constants and store them in a map in the controller:

```
private final Map<RadioButton, String> radioButtonKeys = new HashMap<>();

private static final String ABSOLUTE_PATH_SEARCH = "ABSOLUTE_PATH";
private static final String FILE_NAME_SEARCH = "FILE_NAME";

@FXML
private RadioButton absolutePathRadioButton ;
@FXML
private RadioButton fileNameSearchRadioButton ;
@FXML
private ToggleGroup group ;

public void initialize() {
    radioButtonKeys.put(absolutePathRadioButton, ABSOLUTE_PATH_SEARCH);
    radioButtonKeys.put(fileNameSearchRadioButton, FILE_NAME_SEARCH);
}
```

Now you can write to the file with

```
String searchType = radioButtonKeys.get(group.getSelectedToggle());
// write searchType as the value for Search_Files_Using
```

and you can read back in with

```
String searchType = /* value from file for Search_Files_Using */
for (RadioButton radioButton : radioButtonKeys.keySet()) {
    radioButton.setSelected(radioButtonKeys.get(radioButton).equals(searchType)) ;
}
```

As a slight variant on this you could create an enum instead of using the strings. The advantage here is that you could actually code the search strategy in the enum.

```
public enum SearchType {
    ABSOLUTE_PATH {
        public void search() {
            // search implementation here...
        }
    },
    FILE_NAME {
        public void search() {
            // search implementation here...
        }
    };

    public abstract void search() ;
}
```

(The abstract method can have any signature you need.)

Then you create the map as before, but with the enum values:

```
private final Map<RadioButton, SearchType> radioButtonKeys = new HashMap<>();

public void initialize() {
    radioButtonKeys.put(absolutePathRadioButton, SearchType.ABSOLUTE_PATH);
    radioButtonKeys.put(fileNameSearchRadioButton, SearchType.FILE_NAME);
}
```

and the file read/write is

```
SearchType searchType = radioButtonKeys.get(group.getSelectedToggle());
// write searchType.toString() to file...
```

and

```
String searchType = /* value from file for Search_Files_Using */
for (RadioButton radioButton : radioButtonKeys.keySet()) {
    radioButton.setSelected(radioButtonKeys.get(radioButton) == SearchType.valueOf(searchType)) ;
}
```

The advantage of the enum comes when you actually perform the search:

```
radioButtonKeys.get(group.getSelectedToggle()).search();
```

Just some ideas. The order of the toggle buttons in the toggle group is an implementation of the toggle group, and probably depends on something pretty arbitrary like the order in which they are defined in the FXML file. It would not be robust to rely on that, imho.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your time . I will read it 15 more times to understand it ;0 and implement it :)